# A D range that is RandomAccess and hasLength but not hasSlicing?

Tags: d

In the implementation of `findSplit` in Phobos, we have [this special case](https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/e78bd852a26c1c31c23d1e433f81f7a1d506c1bc/std/algorithm/searching.d#L2915-L2916):

```
static if (isSomeString!R1 && isSomeString!R2
        || (isRandomAccessRange!R1 && hasSlicing!R1 && hasLength!R1 && hasLength!R2))
{
    auto balance = find!pred(haystack, needle);
    immutable pos1 = haystack.length - balance.length;
    immutable pos2 = balance.empty ? pos1 : pos1 + needle.length;
    return Result!(typeof(haystack[0 .. pos1]),
                   typeof(haystack[pos2 .. haystack.length]))(haystack[0 .. pos1],
                                                              haystack[pos1 .. pos2],
                                                              haystack[pos2 .. haystack.length]);
}
```

Most of the constraint makes sense here. I understand that we need a range that is random access and that both the `haystack` and the `needle` need a size. But the `hasSlicing` check is surprising to me.

I would expect any range that is both `RandomAccess` and `hasLength` to be able to support `Slicing`. Is there an example range that inherently fundamentally cannot support `Slicing` despite being `RandomAccess` and `hasLength`?

Or is this more of an issue of user potentially providing a range that simply chose to not implement that particular operation for whatever reason?

Comment: I think your assumption is correct. Ranges are basically just function conventions on custom structs and classes. So for some range struct it is possible to implement the RandomAccess "interface" and a length, but not implement the slicing "interface". RandomAccess ranges are defined as bidirectional ranges that additionally offer `opIndex`. A bidirectional range is a forward range that also offers `back` and `popBack`. A forward range is an input range that also offers `save` and an input range offers `empty`, `front` and `popFront`. Phobos is general purpose so it implements stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went directly to the source with this and asked Andrei Alexandrescu on Twitter. [He responded](https://twitter.com/incomputable/status/1385567013821722624):

> I don't think there's an interesting case of a random access range without slicing (or vice versa). When we introduced ranges we wanted to be as general as possible, but that turned out to be overengineering.